# Starting apache2 failed!

Tags: server, apache2, 16.10

I use

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

answer

```
[....] Reloading apache2 configuration (via systemctl): apache2.serviceapache2.service is not active, cannot reload. failed!
```

I use

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

answer

> [....] Starting apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.serviceJob for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
>   See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
>    failed!

I use

```
journalctl -xe
```

answer

```
янв 03 12:04:11 yura-System-Product-Name gnome-alsamixer[5960]:                                           
gam_toggle_get_state (). No idea what
янв 03 12:04:11 yura-System-Product-Name gnome-alsamixer[5960]:    
gam_toggle_get_state (). No idea what
янв 03 12:04:15 yura-System-Product-Name gnome-alsamixer[5960]: Source ID 89 was not found when attem
янв 03 12:04:39 yura-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: Starting Stop ureadahead data collection...
-- Subject: Unit ureadahead-stop.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit ureadahead-stop.service has begun starting up.
янв 03 12:04:39 yura-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: Started Stop ureadahead data collection.
-- Subject: Unit ureadahead-stop.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit ureadahead-stop.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
янв 03 12:07:36 yura-System-Product-Name polkitd(authority=local)[946]: Registered Authentication Age
янв 03 12:07:36 yura-System-Product-Name polkit-gnome-au[2348]: GtkDialog mapped without a transient 
янв 03 12:07:38 yura-System-Product-Name polkitd(authority=local)[946]: Operator of unix-session:c2 s
янв 03 12:07:38 yura-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up.
янв 03 12:07:38 yura-System-Product-Name apache2[6080]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
янв 03 12:07:38 yura-System-Product-Name apache2[6080]:  *
янв 03 12:07:38 yura-System-Product-Name apache2[6080]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
янв 03 12:07:38 yura-System-Product-Name apache2[6080]: Output of config test was:
янв 03 12:07:38 yura-System-Product-Name apache2[6080]: [Tue Jan 03 12:07:38.432840 2017] [core:warn]
янв 03 12:07:38 yura-System-Product-Name apache2[6080]: [Tue Jan 03 12:07:38.432952 2017] [core:warn]
янв 03 12:07:38 yura-System-Product-Name apache2[6080]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determin
янв 03 12:07:38 yura-System-Product-Name apache2[6080]: (2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot
янв 03 12:07:38 yura-System-Product-Name apache2[6080]: AH00014: Configuration check failed
янв 03 12:07:38 yura-System-Product-Name apache2[6080]: Action 'configtest' failed.
янв 03 12:07:38 yura-System-Product-Name apache2[6080]: The Apache error log may have more informatio
янв 03 12:07:38 yura-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=ex
янв 03 12:07:38 yura-System-Product-Name systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
```

How to correct the error?

Comment: There are an error somewhere in you apache configuration files. Since some of the lines are cut off, I can't see what the error is, but it looks like *Can not reliably establish fully qualified servername' or alike.

Comment: @Nisheet I use sudo a2dismod php7.0 and service apache2 restart. Answer: Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
Does not work.

Comment: @SorenA Files should be checked?

Comment: Just do as the output from journalctl directs you to .. check the apache logs (no, I don't know where they are, it's your system) and fix the configuration item that's in error.

Comment: `apachectl -t` i.e configtest should point you to the syntax error in your apache config files see (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/apachectl.html)